# Python multiprocessing - problem with empty queue and pool freezing

Tags: python, process, queue, multiprocessing, pool

I have problems with python multiprocessing

python version 3.6.6

using Spyder IDE on windows 7

## 1.

queue is not being populated -> everytime I try to read it, its empty. Somewhere I read, that I have to get() it before process join() but it did not solve it.

```
from multiprocessing import Process,Queue

# define a example function
def fnc(i, output):    
    output.put(i)    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Define an output queue
    output = Queue()

    # Setup a list of processes that we want to run
    processes = [Process(target=fnc, args=(i, output)) for i in range(4)]
    print('created')

    # Run processes
    for p in processes:
        p.start()
    print('started')

    # Exit the completed processes        
    for p in processes:
        p.join()
        
    print(output.empty())
    print('finished')

>>>created
>>>started
>>>True
>>>finished
```

I would expect output to not be empty.

if I change it from .join() to

```
    for p in processes:
        print(output.get())
        #p.join()
```

it freezes

## 2.

Next problem I have is with pool.map() - it freezes and has no chance to exceed memory limit. I dont even know how to debug such simple pieace of code.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x):
    return x*x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(processes=4)
    print('Pool created')
    # print "[0, 1, 4,..., 81]"
    print(pool.map(f, range(10))) # it freezes here
```

Hope its not a big deal to have two questions in one topic

Comment: Apart from using `queue.empty()` checks (not reliable) your code looks fine. Spyder at least _was_ known for having problems with multiprocessing. Try with running your code from terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Apperently the problem is Spyder's IPython console. When I run both from cmd, its executed properly.

---

## Solution

for debugging in Spyder add `.dummy` to multiprocessing import

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Process,Queue
```

It will not be executed by more processors, but you will get results and can actualy see the output. When debugging is done simply delete `.dummy`, place it in another file, import it and call it for example as function

### multiprocessing_my.py

```
from multiprocessing import Process,Queue

# define a example function
def fnc(i, output):
    output.put(i)
    print(i)

def test():
    # Define an output queue
    output = Queue()
    # Setup a list of processes that we want to run
    processes = [Process(target=fnc, args=(i, output)) for i in range(4)]
    print('created')
    # Run processes
    for p in processes:
        p.start()
    print('started')
    # Exit the completed processes

    for p in processes:    
        p.join()

    print(output.empty())
    print('finished')

    # Get process results from the output queue
    results = [output.get() for p in processes]
    print('get results')
    print(results)
```

---

### test_mp.py

executed by selecting code and pressing ctrl+Enter

```
import multiprocessing_my

multiprocessing_my.test2()
```

...

```
In[9]: test()
    created
    0
    1
    2
    3
    started
    False
    finished
    get results
    [0, 1, 2, 3]
```